# Is Bootstrap already installed with VS.NET 2015?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I have the VS.NET 2015 CTP.  I've created a web app and selected to install a nuget package.  I select Twitter.Bootstrap.Less and install.  I see a green check mark next to this package in the nuget window.  I close this window but don't notice a content folder in my project.

When I open the wwwroot > lib folder, I see:

```
bootstrap
bootstrap-touch-carousel
```

Those were there before I installed the bootstrap package.

Does bootstrap come default with web apps in vs.net 2015?

I installed the bootstrap nuget but the content folder isn't there and I don't see any other package downloads.  Any idea where the package content went?

Comment: Isn't bower included in VS2015? for clientside resources I would use bower and for serverside nuget

Comment: Isn't that kind of the formal role of those two - bower==client side & nuget ==all else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you selected ASP.Net 5 Preview Starter Web Template? In that case it does include BootStrap and BootStrap-Touch-Carousel within the project template.

If you take a look inside the Bower.json file, or within the Dependencies -> Bower folder, you can see what is included in this template. I might be wrong, but I think that the Preview Starter Web Template is the only one that includes these out of the gate.